# Best Practices for organizing different code for phone and tablet

Tags: android

I'm adapting an existing phone application for tablets. The problem is that there are some small differences in the UI between the phone and the tablet.

For example, on the phone, there is a landing page and then a login page with a cancel button that goes back too the landing page.

On the tablet, the login fragment is on the landing page and the cancel button is removed. This means that I've made a check to see if the device is a tablet and if it is, I dunno find the view of the cancel button.

This seems hacky to me and i was wondering if there was a better way to do this. Thanks.

Comment: You can define/manage different layout xml files and made changes accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Tablet or phone ?**

First of all you should know on which device you are. An elegant way (in my opinion) is to declare a resource in config.xml :

*values/config.xml*

```
<bool name="isTablet">false</bool>
```

*values-sw600dp/config.xml*

```
<bool name="isTablet">true</bool>
```

Then extends [Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) and keep the type of device running the app :

```
public static boolean IS_TABLET = false;
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    MyApp.IS_TABLET     = getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.isTablet);
}
```

**Handling differents view**

To handle differents view use the differents folders in /res

/layout for phone view
/layout-sw600dp for 7" tablet (you can just use this folder if there is no difference between 7 et 10")
/layout-sw720dp for 10" tablet

**Handling code**

Two solutions here :

1- The change between views are minor : keep the same activity/fragment and add some condition like

```
if(MyAPP.IS_TABLET) {
   // DO something on tablet
} else {
   // Do something on phone
}
```

2- If tablet and phone are very different create a new activity/fragment with a suffixe like :
HomeActvity => HomeActivityTablet
And add a condition on the loading of this particular view.

You can also works with differents namespace , depending on what give you best architecture.

**Exemple**

Have a look on the [Google IO app's](https://github.com/google/iosched/tree/master/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched) source code